# Exchange Degeneracy of Fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Suppose that two identical fermions 1 and 2 are in the following antisymmetric state:

$|\Psi_{1}\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2}(|A\rangle|B\rangle - |B\rangle|A\rangle)$,

where $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are orthonormal.

Now, this state is not permutation invariant in the strict sense, for if you exchange the particles 1 and 2, or apply the permutation operator $P_{21}$ to $|\Psi _{1} \rangle$, you get:

$P_{21}|\Psi_{1} \rangle = |\Psi _{2}\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2}(|B\rangle|A\rangle - |A\rangle|B\rangle)$,

and $|\Psi_{1} \rangle \neq |\Psi_{2}\rangle$, from a mathematical point of view.

From a physical point of view, their expectation values would be identical for all observables. That is,

$\langle \Psi_{1}|O|\Psi_{1}\rangle = \langle \Psi_{2}|O|\Psi_{2}\rangle$ for any Hermitian operator $O$ representing some observable for the composite system of 1 and 2.

This looks like an example of degeneracy. You have two mathmatically distinct states corresponding to the same empirical result all the time. In this case, should we say that $\Psi_{1}$ and $\Psi_{2}$ are two distinct states or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remember that two states differing by an overall phase are considered physically identical.
2. Note that the particle exchange operator has the following property here: $$P_{21}|\Psi_1\rangle=-|\Psi_1\rangle.$$ So these *are* distinct elements of the two-particle Hilbert space but since they only differ by a total factor of $\text e^{i\pi}=-1$ they correspond to identical *physical* states. This is then in line with the idea that these particles are "identical", no physical experiment can be done that distinguishes $|\Psi_1\rangle$ and $|\Psi_2\rangle$.

Comment: You might want to clarify that, while global phase doesn't matter, phase differences do matter (physics.stackexchange.com/q/552796).  For example, the change of sign under particle exchange is what distinguishes fermions from bosons.